# Unable to use IAM Access control method using terraform aws_msk_cluster resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-msk

I am trying to develop a module to create AWS MSK. I would like to enable IAM authentication for MSK resource
I am following the below link, but I don't see anything related to IAM authentication.
[(https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/msk_cluster#sasl)]

```
dynamic "client_authentication" {
   for_each = var.client_tls_auth_enabled || var.client_sasl_iam_enabled ? [1] : []
   content {
     dynamic "tls" {
       for_each = var.client_tls_auth_enabled ? [1] : []
       content {
         certificate_authority_arns = var.certificate_authority_arns
       }
     }
     dynamic "sasl" {
       for_each = var.client_sasl_iam_enabled ? [1] : []
       content {
         iam = var.client_sasl_iam_enabled
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

> **Error: An argument named "iam" is not expected here.**

Comment: The feature you are trying to use is less than 2 weeks old and not yet supported by terraform: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/19295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary update your aws provider at least v3.43.0: [see changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v3.43.0/CHANGELOG.md)

e.g.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  required_providers {
    aws    = ">= 3.43.0"
  }
}
```

it's really works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what? CF doesn't have it either. There is a PR for tf with support for it. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/19404

Comment: Thanks Frank, I found that Can you please give a thumps up to support MR please :p