# AWS MSK Connect with IAM - Timeout Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I have a setup with a MSK Cluster and an MSK Connect Connector (which is a source connector to a postgres db, but that shouldn't matter here).

During the first step of my setup, it set it all up without authentication. And it worked fine.

Now, as my next step, I introduced TLS and IAM based authentication. But I end up with a         `"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: fetchMetadata"`

I have already tried all answers to [AWS MSK with IAM - Timeout Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67487870/aws-msk-with-iam-timeout-exception).

What I did specifically:
I gave my Connect-Cluster the additional AWS-managed policy "AmazonMSKFullAccess", so it can perform all actions on MSK.
And then I added Outbound- and Inbound- Rules to the security group of my MSK cluster so Port 9098 can be reached from within this same security group.

After I updated the configuration of the MSK cluster so only IAM auth is supported, I specifically did not re-create my connector (assuming this was not necessary).

Does anyone have an idea what could be missing?

Best greetings

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad. The old Connector was still set to unauthenticated access - I needed to create a new one with the authentication method "IAM".